# 2 USB Headsets, 1 PC, 1 Skype account

Tags: usb, windows-vista, headset

We use Skype to call our parents overseas to a landline, and would like to use 2 USB Headsets at the same time on our side. Can it be done?

Comment: Related question (but about regular headphones, not usb ones): http://superuser.com/questions/88950/skype-2-headsets-on-one-computer

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just setup another account (which is free)?

Grab the **[Skype Launcher](http://download.cnet.com/SkypeLauncher/3000-2349_4-10844575.html)** (also free and portable), a utility to run multiple instances of Skype on one computer. Use the second headset as audio device for the second Skype session and make a conference call.

Comment: Is that can cause interference? Even if they have 2 Skype account working at the same time on the same computer, this won't change anything to the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure, but I think you can't use two different sound devices in windows at the same time in the same application. Each USB headphone is it's own device, so that's where you would have the problem.

A much easier solution would be to get an adapter that has 2 inputs and 1 output. You would need regular headphones instead of USB ones, though.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: I think you can use two different sound devices in some applications (finally, you can point to different devices for recording and playback), but I don't think that Skype allows it.

Comment: I think USB are their own devices so even if he uses Skype or another application, Windows can't stream on a SPDIF output at the same time on a USB sound device. So, I assume that it's not functionnal. definitely, I need to test it out! haha

Answer (score 1):

I know this is the wrong answer to this question and don't expect any votes but for posterity.

We do the same thing several times a week with remote kids. Our solution which is much more comfortable was to get a web-cam that has a mic with fantastic range (we chose a Labtec 2200, $8 on Ebay). Then got an inexpensive set of USB laptop speakers. Even when we don't do video, we still use the camera mic because it is just more comfortable and offers better sound than the headsets. I can be anywhere in the room and speak conversationally with no problems.

Comment: For now we use a separate 'inexpensive' mic with the PC speakers- the quality of the sound received on the other side is reported to be not as good as when we use the headset. Our webcam does not have a mic. Probably will have to invest in one...