# Is it possible to connect and use two bluetooth headsets on one pc?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, webrtc

I want to connect two bluetooth headsets to one laptop and give them to two people to join a WebRTC conference call. Is it possible to get it working without additional hardware(for example by opening two instances of Chrome)?

Comment: Each device is different “audio” hardware. So if you can run more than one instance of the application and choose a different audio output destination for each then it should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [skype + 2 headsets on one computer](https://superuser.com/questions/88950/skype-2-headsets-on-one-computer)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a duplicate, I'd like to know specifically about bluetooth devices.